# How do you prove that the determinant of a 3 by 3 matrix with entries of either 1 and -1 (assume linearly independent rows) will always be 4 or -4?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Assume that A is a $3\times3$ matrix, where all entries are either $1$ or  $-1$ and the rows are linearly independent.

Why is it the case that the determinant will always be $4$ or $-4$?

Comment: It is by symmetry: we're considering 3 vertices of the cube $(\pm1, \, \pm1,\, \pm1)$.

Comment: Could you please expand on that? I'm not quite grasping it.

Comment: Are you asking for a proof or some geometric intuition?

Comment: I am asking for a proof.

Comment: @Berci What is the symmetry argument? Do you check several cases separately? Up to symmetries of the cube, there still seem to be 3 non-equivalent ways of choosing 3 distinct vertices.

Answer (score 11):

HINT:

Add the first column to column $2$ and $3$. The determinant does not change. Now the new columns $2$ and $3$ are divisible by $2$. So the determinant is divisible by $4$.

The determinant has $6$ terms, each $\pm 1$. So it is between $-6$ and $6$.

Comment: Neatest proof and shortest. Uses no more than very elementary fact about determinant. +1

Answer (score 5):

Here is a slightly obscure proof, just for fun.

As all entries of $A$ are equal to $\pm1$, the diagonal entries of $A^TA$ are equal to $3$ and the off-diagonal entries of $A^TA$ are odd numbers between $-3$ and $3$. However, as $A$ is supposed to be nonsingular, $A^TA$ is positive definite. Thus its principal $2\times2$ submatrices are positive definite too. It follows that the off-diagonal entries of $A^TA$ cannot be equal to $\pm3$ and they can only be equal to $\pm1$. Therefore, by negating the appropriate rows of $A$ if necessary, we may assume that
$$
A^TA=\pmatrix{3&1&1\\ 1&3&s\\ 1&s&3}
$$
where $s=\pm1$. Hence $\det(A^TA)$ is equal to $20$ when $s=1$, and $16$ when $s=-1$. As $A$ is an integer matrix, $\det(A^TA)=\det(A)^2$ must be a perfect square. Therefore $\det(A)^2=16$ and $\det(A)=\pm4$.

Answer (score 4):

Since multiplying a row of $A$ by a constant $c$ changes the determinant from $\det(A)$ to $c\times\det(A)$, we may multiply rows by $\pm1$ and suppose that 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\1&c&d\\1&e&f\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since subtracting a row by another row does not affect the determinant, we may change $A$ to be of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&c-a&d-b\\0&e-a&f-b\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Noticing that we cannot have $c-a=e-a=0$, otherwise the rows are not linearly independent, we may assume that this is of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&\pm2&d-b\\0&e-a&f-b\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now if $e-a=0$, then $f-b\ne0$, so $f-b=\pm2$ and $\det(A)=\pm4$. If $e-a\ne0$, then $e-a=\pm2=\pm(c-a)$.

If $e-a=c-a$, then we may subtract the third row by the second row, and $A$ becomes
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&\pm2&d-b\\0&0&f-d\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Again this implies $\det(A)=\pm4$.

But $e-a$ cannot be equal to $-(c-a)$, since this means $e+c=2a$, which implies $e=c$ and hence $e-a=c-a$, a contradiction.

---

If there is any error or confusion, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the following row/column operations will only change the determinant by a negative sign:

1. Multiply a row/column by $-1$;
2. Swap two rows/columns.

From here on we only use these two operations.

Now let's start with an arbitrary $3\times3$ matrix with $\pm1$ entries. You make the necessary row multiplications by $-1$ to make the first column entries all $1$. The second column would have one or two entries, but not zero or three entries, being $-1$, due to assumption that the matrix has linearly independent rows (which is equivalent to having linearly independent columns). If it is two entries being $-1$, multiply second column by $-1$ so that it is just one entry being $-1$. Also swap rows so that it is the first row of second column being $-1$.

Now the third column can't have the second and third entries being both $1$ or both $-1$ or the columns are linearly dependent. They must be different. The first entry can be either $1$ or $-1$.

The matrix obtained looks like $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&a\\1&1&\pm1\\1&1&\mp1\end{bmatrix}$$ where $a$ is either $1$ or $-1$. You can solve for the determinant of this resulting matrix as $\pm4$. The initial matrix's determinant is the same of the last matrix's, or is the negative, because the row/column operations only change the determinant's sign.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun,
this is the dum?best proof by exhaustion,
to quickly check the stated fact.

For a small-sized matrices
it is easy to enumerate all of them,
using a spreadsheet.

For the $3\times 3$ case
we can put each of the matrix with $\pm1$ elements element-wise in a row of 9 elements,
$2^9=512$ rows in total, add a column with the formula of the determinant,
and then use `countif()` formula to find out that 
along with 320 zero elements, 
there are $96$ matrices with $\det=-4$
and the same amount for $\det=4$, $512$ in total,
that is, there are no any other values of determinants.

The table itself is very easy to build, similarly to the true table 
for a boolean function of $9$ elements, but using $-1$ instead of $0$,
starting with the row of nine $-1$ entries.

Similarly, one can find out that for $4\times4$ matrices
possible determinants are $\pm8$ and $\pm16$.

Comment: Interesting idea. Note that by changing signs of rows, and then columns, we can arrange that the first row and column consists of $1$. Now we can also permute rows and columns $2-4$.  Interesting thing is why we cannot have det $=\pm 24$ ( we know it's divisible by $8$).

Comment: @orangeskid: Just in case, for $5\times5$ matrices possible determinants are $\pm16$, $\pm32$ and $\pm48$.

Comment: Great point!  We know they are divisible by $2^{5-1}=16$, and Hadamard inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality tells us the determinant in absolute value does not exceed $5^{5/2}=55.9...$, so it must be one of the divisors of $16$ of absolute value $<64$.  I wonder if there are more restrictions for $n=6$ than the similar ones.

Comment: For $n=6$, $|\det|\le 6^{6/2}=216$, and divisible by $2^5=32$, so can be in principle any multiple of $32$ up to $\pm 6\cdot 32 = \pm192$. Are all of them achieved? Interesting...

Comment: @orangeskid: For $6\times6$ $|det_\max|=160$,
see [A003433](http://oeis.org/A003433);
I confirm that matrices with $|\operatorname{det}|=32,64,96,128,160$ indeed exist.
Interesting, that Number of $n\times n\ \pm1 $-matrices having determinant 
$A003433(n)$, [A188895](http://oeis.org/A188895) stops at $n=5$.

Comment: I think this PPT document addressing the maximal determinant problem is quite interesting. https://caramel.loria.fr/sem-slides/200904301100.pdf

Comment: @awllower: Thanks, it is indeed interesting.

Comment: up to $n=6$, all the possible values between the $\min$ and the $\max$ are achieved.  Would that be true for $n=7$?  I am not sure how much computation that would involve, although just checking that some value appears would be easier.  Also, can reduce the number of matrices to check by ordering the columns $2-n$ in lexicographic order.

Comment: @orangeskid: 
I found $7\times7$ matrices with 
$\det=64,128,192,256,320,384,448,512,576$,
that is, $64\cdot 1,\dots, 64\cdot 9$.
Other theoretically possible, $64\cdot10,\dots, 64\cdot 14$
are most probably too rare to show up in the random search.

Comment: @g.kov:  looking at http://oeis.org/A003433  shows that the maximal value is indeed $576$ and from your search all possible smaller values are also achieved.  Interesting fact! (Reducing to determinants with entries $0$ and $1$ might make the random search a bit easier?)

Answer (score 0):

By hypothesis, $A$ has the form
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
(-1)^a&(-1)^b&(-1)^c\\
(-1)^d&(-1)^e&(-1)^f\\
(-1)^g&(-1)^h&(-1)^i
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i\in\{0,1\}$. Therefore, a straightforward computation shows that
$$\det A=(-1)^{a}\Big[(-1)^{e + i}+(-1)^{f + h+1}\Big] + (-1)^{b}\Big[(-1)^{f + g} +(-1)^{d + i+1}\Big]\\ +(-1)^{c}\Big[(-1)^{d + h} + (-1)^{e + g +1}\Big]$$

Let us write
$$r=e+i,\quad s=f+h+1,\quad t=f+g,\quad u=d+i+1,\quad v=d+h,\quad w=e+g+1.$$

Then,
$$w=r+t-s-u+v+3$$
and thus
$$\det A=(-1)^{a}\underbrace{\Big[(-1)^{r}+(-1)^{s}\Big]}_{X} + (-1)^{b}\underbrace{\Big[(-1)^{t} +(-1)^{u}\Big]}_{Y} \\+(-1)^{c+v}\underbrace{\Big[1 + (-1)^{r+t-s-u+1}\Big]}_{Z}
$$

From this equality, we conclude that:

- If all numbers $r,s,t,u$ are even, then $X=Y=2$ and $Z=0$. Therefore,
  $$\det A=\pm4\quad \text{ or }\quad \det A=0.$$
- If exactly three of the numbers $r,s,t,u$ are even, then exactly one of the numbers $X,Y$ is $0$, the other is $2$ and $Z=2$. Therefore,
  $$\det A=\pm4\quad \text{ or }\quad \det A=0.$$
- If exactly two of the numbers $r,s,t,u$ are even, then $X=-Y\in\{0,2\}$ and $Z=0$. Therefore,
  $$\det A=\pm4\quad \text{ or }\quad \det A=0.$$
- If exactly one of the numbers $r,s,t,u$ is even, then exactly one of the numbers $X,Y$ is $0$, the other is $2$ and $Z=2$. Therefore,
  $$\det A=\pm4\quad \text{ or }\quad \det A=0.$$
- If all numbers $r,s,t,u$ are odd, then $X=Y=-2$ and $Z=0$. Therefore,
  $$\det A=\pm4\quad \text{ or }\quad \det A=0.$$

Since $\det A\neq 0$ by hypothesis, it follows that $\det A =\pm 4$.